# Normalise JSON for flexible WebAPI response

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI method that returns Json in a flexible structure that depends on the request.

Part of the problem is that there could be any number of columns, and they could be any type. The 2 given below (Code and Count) are just one example.

This structure is based on the underlying classes but there could be any number of columns in the output. So, rather than the usual properties you might expect, these are objects in a collection with `Name` and `Value` properties.

The downside of this flexible approach is that it gives a non-standard format.

Is there a way to transform this into a more normalised shape? Are there maybe some attributes I can add to the class properties to change the way they are serialised?

For example, where there are 2 columns - `Code` (string) and `Count` (numeric):

Current Json:

```
{
    "Rows": [
        {
            "Columns": [
                {
                    "Value": "1",
                    "Name": "Code"
                },
                {
                    "Value": 13,
                    "Name": "Count"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Columns": [
                {
                    "Value": "2",
                    "Name": "Code"
                },
                {
                    "Value": 12,
                    "Name": "Count"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Columns": [
                {
                    "Value": "9",
                    "Name": "Code"
                },
                {
                    "Value": 1,
                    "Name": "Count"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Columns": [
                {
                    "Value": "5",
                    "Name": "Code"
                },
                {
                    "Value": 2,
                    "Name": "Count"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Ideally I'd like to transform it to this:

```
{
    "Rows": [
        {
            "Code": "1",
            "Count": 13
        },
        {
            "Code": "2",
            "Count": 12
        },
        {
            "Code": "9",
            "Count": 1
        },
        {
            "Code": "5",
            "Count": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

The controller method (C#)

```
    public ReportResponse Get(ReportRequest request)
    {
        var result = ReportLogic.GetReport(request);
        return result;
    }
```

The output classes

```
public class ReportResponse
{
    public List<ReportRow> Rows { get; set; }
    public ReportResponse()
    {
        Rows = new List<ReportRow>();
    }
}
public class ReportRow
{
    public List<ReportColumn> Columns { get; set; }
    public ReportRow()
    {
        Columns = new List<ReportColumn>();
    }
}
public class ReportColumn<T> : ReportColumn
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public ReportColumn(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
public abstract class ReportColumn
{
    public string Name { get; internal set; }
}
```

Comment: Discover the _mana from heaven_ that is [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm).  That should get you going

Comment: Oo never heard of that - looking it up now :D

Comment: What is the structure you are returning? You may do some linqy things on it before returning

Comment: Just to be a pain, your desired output is actually invalid json. I assume you just want the array output?

Comment: @Padraic yes that is correct :p

Comment: Ok I can see you're still returning the `ReportResponse` class from your controller action. You will need to return an instance of a class that reflects the JSON format you desire.

Comment: @Padraic Yes that would be the easiest way, unfortunately as stated, the output is flexible and could have any number and type of data columns. Because of that, no single class will work, which is why I need a way to transform the output Json.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to map your class to a dictionary before serializing. Something like:

```
var dictionaries = List<Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach(var column in rows.Columns)
{
    dictionaries.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>{{column.Name, column.Value}});
}
```

Then serialize the dictionaries variable should do the trick.

Comment: I'm sure the LINQ-y folk will have a more succinct way to do it!

Comment: Not all the column values are strings though. Is there a way to preserve the types?

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G Instead of Dictionary<string, string> you could use Dictionary<string, object> which would accept value wolf any type and preserve the type when serialized.

Comment: Actually this doesn't help, I still get the original structure.

Comment: Are you returning the new dictionary from your web api controller action?

Comment: Yes, but it is the same shape as the original class structure so the serialised output looks the same. There is no single structure I can rely on as there could be any number of columns, of any type. I need to somehow affect the serialisation so that columns are serialised differently than standard, i.e. correctly.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using the output in JavaScript, you could translate as follows:

```
    var
        data = {
            "Rows": [
                {
                    "Columns": [
                        {
                            "Value": "1",
                            "Name": "Code"
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": 13,
                            "Name": "Count"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Columns": [
                        {
                            "Value": "2",
                            "Name": "Code"
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": 12,
                            "Name": "Count"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Columns": [
                        {
                            "Value": "9",
                            "Name": "Code"
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": 1,
                            "Name": "Count"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Columns": [
                        {
                            "Value": "5",
                            "Name": "Code"
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": 2,
                            "Name": "Count"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        output = [
        ];

    data.Rows.forEach(function (row)
    {
        var
            newRow = {};

        row.Columns.forEach(function (column)
        {
            newRow[column.Name] = column.Value;
        });

        output.push(newRow);
    })

    console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: bambam are you heard about the map function??

Comment: Sorry I meant I'd like to transform the Json in C#, before I return it.

Comment: @dobleUber - nope, tell me more.

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G - no problem! It was a suggestion without knowing how large your data set is or how it's being consumed.

Comment: @bambam check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map